# Create MS Word template from image

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have a letterhead designed. It's in Adobe Illustrator (AI), PDF, PNG, and EPS, formats.

I am trying to create a template for MS Word using the letterhead as the background image.

When I use the option to set a background image in word it uses the correct image, but stretches it a lot. The letterhead is 8.5" x 11", but when I set it as the background image in Word it only shows a part of it and most of it is cut off because Word increases the image size so much.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut the header and footer out of the letterhead into their own, separate graphic files.

Insert the header graphic into Word's "Header" section, and insert the footer graphic into Word's "Footer" section.

Adjust the inserted graphics' positioning and dimensions as desired.

[More info on Headers and Footers in Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/insert-headers-and-footers-HP001226486.aspx)

Example (Word 2013) of a gradient + graphical text image (PNG) inserted into the footer, as described above:

[image: Word 2013 with gradient image in footer]

The Image was formatted to place itself "Behind text" to make positioning it easier.  I was able to resize and adjust it freely, so the aspect ratio could easily be maintained.

Here it is with some text in the body, which has had its "Shading" (Borders and Shading) set to "No Color" so the text background is transparent:

[image: Word with gradient background foot and text]

Comment: That was my original thought, except that the letterhead has a slight gradient image that covers the bottom half of the page, so I don't think this would work properly.

Comment: @SherwinFlight I edited my answer to include an example showing that it works as described. :)

Comment: Not having much luck this way. I can get it set the way you say, but then there's only a very small portion of the page that you can actually type on. The gradient on the bottom is very light, and meant to be written over. So when I set that as the footer I can't type over it (unless adding footer text)

Comment: I should also note that it's not just a standard gradient, but more like a watermark image that fades as you go up the page.

Basically I have a full-page image that I want as a full-page template in Word.

Comment: "but then there's only a very small portion of the page that you can actually type on.", and you formatted the picture you inserted and chose it's text-alignment to be "Behind text"?  What version of Word are you using?

Comment: For example, in your image, I would be able to type in the space under the "Header" box, to the line in the middle of the page. Word 2010

Comment: @techie007 Since I actually read some of that text I'm hungry. All texts are better when they start with bacon. LOL Thanks!

Comment: @SherwinFlight "to the line in the middle of the page", that sounds like you're hitting the top of the image because you didn't format it to be "Behind Text".  I've asked a couple times now but haven't gotten an answer -- Did you actually do that?

Comment: I did try that, and it still didn't work. I closed Word, and started completely from scratch again and it worked the way you said. Setting it to "behind text" worked and solved the problem. Marking this answer as correct. Thanks for the help techie007 :)